# Where can I find the teleport?

Tags: candy-box-2

I need to get the chocolate bars in the hole, but I can't get out of there. Where can I find the pogo stick or teleport?

Answer (score 2):

For the pogo stick: Click on the * on the mountains while on the map.  For the teleport: You buy it from the witch, it is the eight book from left to right on the lower shelf.

Answer (score 0):

To get the teleport spell, buy the first grimoire from the sorceress. Click the book on the shelf to buy it.

Answer (score 0):

[image]The grimoire for the teleport spell is the eighth book from the left on the lower shelf in the Sorceress's hut and the pogo stick is found in the mountain range where the asterisk is circled.